# Karma testing with Angular2: Unexpected anonymous System.register call

Tags: typescript, jasmine, angular, karma-runner, systemjs

When I run Karma Tests in Angular2 i get the following error.

Uncaught TypeError: Unexpected anonymous System.register call.
at http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?38538ebca96bc7b222f7e7ba15943f173a485f6e:2885

I suppose its because the var System is currently not available. Even if its actually loaded.
Does anyone have an idea why this is not working?

### Here is my stripped down configuration:

C:\project\karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
      'tests/**/*Spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

---

C:\project\tests\MyTestSpec.ts
This one line is enough to trigger the error.

```
import {describe, expect, it, xit, inject, beforeEachProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
```

---

that renders to 
C:\project\tests\MyTestSpec.js
and produces an error on the first occurance of System

```
System.register([], function(exports_1) {
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=CmiCloudSpec.js.map
```

---

C:\project\tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "watch": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

---

C:\project\src\node_modules

contains the folders angular2 and systemjs as well as karma, karma-jasmine, jasmine-core and typescript

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should include all your test files into Karma directly within the `files` attribute of `karma.conf.js`. Because you don't define an `outFile` property in your tsc configuration (and that's fine here), the name of modules aren't specified into the compiled JS files.

You need rather to create a `karma-test-shim.js` file (that will be included) and configure SystemJS to load module by file names and import these file using `System.import`.

Here is a sample of `karma-test-shim.js` file:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

__karma__.loaded = function() {};

System.config({
  packages: {
    'base/dist': {
        defaultExtension: false,
        format: 'cjs',
        map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(onlyAppFiles).reduce(createPathRecords, {})
    }
  }
});

System.import('angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter')
  .then(function(browser_adapter) { browser_adapter.BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent(); })
  .then(function() { return Promise.all(resolveTestFiles()); })
  .then(function() { __karma__.start(); }, function(error) { __karma__.error(error.stack || error); });

function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
  var pathParts = appPath.split('/');
  var moduleName = './' + pathParts.slice(Math.max(pathParts.length - 2, 1)).join('/');
  moduleName = moduleName.replace(/\.js$/, '');
  pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath];
  return pathsMapping;
}

function onlyAppFiles(filePath) {
  return /\/base\/dist\/(?!.*\.spec\.js$).*\.js$/.test(filePath);
}

function onlySpecFiles(path) {
  return /\.spec\.js$/.test(path);
}

function resolveTestFiles() {
  return Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
    .filter(onlySpecFiles)
    .map(function(moduleName) {
        return System.import(moduleName);
    });
}
```

and the corresponding configuration in `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      // paths loaded by Karma
      {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js', included: true, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true},

      // paths loaded via module imports
      {pattern: 'dist/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},

      // paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
      {pattern: 'src/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'dist/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],
    (...)
  });
};
```

It think that this article and its source code could help you:

- http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2016/01/testing-angular-2-with-karma-and-jasmine/
- https://github.com/Elecash/angular2-testing

Comment: Did OP find this answer helpful? Should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. The explanation that the bundled files in 'tests/**/*Spec.js' could not be loaded made perfect sense.

And it is working now.

To keep the explanation simple I added the karma-test-shim.js to the files section and that was it.

I will change the files section style later.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
      'karma-test-shim.js',
      'tests/**/*Spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing was necessary in the `karma.conf.js` file

```
basePath: '.',

proxies: {
    // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
    '/src/': '/base/src/'
},
```

Needed because otherwise the tests will not be executed